# AngularJS : undoing changes in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create an edit-in-place directive. What I'm currently stuck with is the ability to cancel edits. I'm trying to copy the model using $parse and then setting it back using assign, but while the elements change, the underlying model does not.

Please find it at http://goo.gl/3ALOQd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code did not work is that `$parse(expression).assign($scope, val)` will replace the value with mine. In this case, the value is `contact` which is an object reference to the array of objects in the controller scope. When I set my own value, this replaces the reference with a reference to another object

Comment: Can you please attach the fiddle with answer. I wanted to know what you did? because i spend more than hour to figure out this.